# Group Concatenate results of a Derived Table

Tags: mysql

I have a query, a generalized version of which I've reproduced below:

`SELECT TT.column
FROM Table1 TT
JOIN Table2 T USING (PRIMARYKEY)
GROUP BY T.Date`

I want to take the output of this query -- a single column output with multiple rows sorted by date -- and group concat it in another query as a derived table:

```
SELECT 
T.column2,
GROUP_CONCAT(
SELECT TT.column
FROM Table1 TT
JOIN Table2 T USING (PRIMARYKEY)
GROUP BY T.Date) AS concat_output
FROM Table1 TT
JOIN Table2 T USING (PRIMARYKEY)
GROUP BY T.Date
```

However, this returns an error at the line of the `GROUP_CONCAT` command.

Thoughts on how to make this work?

EDIT: To give some more detail on why I wanted the derived table to work:

At the moment, without using `GROUP_CONCAT`, I get multiple rows that look like

```
a
a
b
b
a 
a
c
c 
d
a
```

If I try to `GROUP_CONCAT` as described by Mukesh's answer, using `DISTINCT` I get the following, for example, as a row: `a, b, c, d` when really I want `a,b,a,c,d,a`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
T.column2,
GROUP_CONCAT(
 DISTINCT TT.column
) AS concat_output
FROM Table1 TT
JOIN Table2 T USING (PRIMARYKEY)
GROUP BY T.Date
```

More detail to refer this link

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: Thanks, although see the edit in my question for a slightly different question.